# How to fire 'print' of summernote-ext-print from javascript?

Tags: javascript, summernote

I'm using `summernote-ext-print` plugin to print content. 
`Summernote` element is part of simple form for article fields.
I would like to perform a click programmatically on button `print`, before the form is submitted. How to do this?

Comment: on Form submit call the method which is the event handler of click!

Comment: Of course I know I can search all the button with label "print" or something within the summernote element and fire a 'click', but I'm looking for more API oriented solution.